# Error after xcode 8 update - NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, ios10

After updating to Xcode 8.0 and iOS 10, I am getting an error in my code that I didn't before. Let me just walk you through the code that is bugging me.

viewDidLoad:

```
struct defaultsKeys {
    static var localStrings = ""
}
```

Outside button (IBAction):

```
var storeUserData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

Inside button (IBAction):

```
let earlierStrings = storeUserData.stringForKey("localStrings")
```

The last one, inside the button, is the line that is giving me an error. I am now getting this error: 
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

And I wasn't before the update? Has something changed about NSUserDefaults? I am very confused and I hope you can help me :-)

Comment: You're getting the value against a string, rather the variable `localStrings` here: storeUserData.stringForKey("localStrings").

Comment: @AdilSoomro so what are you saying? :-)

Comment: "Outside button", "Inside Button" — are you using user defaults for passing stuff around? Dont do so.

Comment: You're passing localStrings with double quotes like this: `"localStrings"` it changes things.

Comment: @AdilSoomro thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want to pass around values inside your program just use local variables as @vikingosegundo stated. Declare local variables and use them.

Second, use NSUserDefault when you want to store variables like for example user-settings or preferences. Do also follow @Adils advice. Use them as follows:

Set value:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("YOUR STRING", forKey: "key")
```

Get value:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("key")
```